# [IntelliJ IDEA plugin development]Black screen will disappear while switching between opened pages if an HTML page was loaded After IntelliJ IDEA 2022

Tags: java, intellij-plugin

**To create the cefBrowser, follow the steps below:**

```
cefBrowser = jbCefClient.getCefClient().createBrowser("file:///xxxxx", false, false);

jPanel.add(cefBrowser.getUIComponent(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

use this api:

```
public CefBrowser createBrowser(String url, boolean isOffscreenRendered, boolean isTransparent) {
        return this.createBrowser(url, isOffscreenRendered, isTransparent, (CefRequestContext)null);
    }
```

**When you switch between multiple pages, a black screen occurs and the page content is lost.**

*Before switching pages:*
The HTML page is displayed properly.

*After clicking Switch Page：*

All HTML GUI elements are lost, and a black screen is displayed.

**Problem decribed above can be regenerated under #IU-221.5591.52 Runtime version: 11.0.14.1+1-b2043.45 amd64. For previous versions, the function is normal.**

In IntelliJ IDEA 2022 and later versions, when multiple HTML pages created using JCEF are opened, the GUI elements are normal and no black screen is displayed after multiple clicks.

Comment: You also asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77252860/intellij-idea-plugin-developmentblack-screen-will-disappear-while-switching-be) one day earlier.